# Android sort arraylist by properties

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort an `ArrayList` by a property. This is my code...

```
public class FishDB{

    public static Object Fish;
    public ArrayList<Fish> list = new ArrayList<Fish>();

    public class Fish{
        String name;
        int length;
        String LatinName;
        //etc. 

        public Vis (String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public FishDB() {
        Fish fish;

        fish = new Fish("Shark");
        fish.length = 200;
        fish.LatinName = "Carcharodon Carcharias";

        fish = new Fish("Rainbow Trout");
        fish.length = 80;
        fish.LatinName = "Oncorhynchus Mykiss";

        //etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want in want to sort this `ArrayList` by a property e.g the `latinname` in another activity. But I don't know how to do that. Does anybody know how?

Comment: try `Collections.sort(arrayList);`

Comment: @Lucifer If you do that, then the generic type of your arrayList should implement java.lang.Comparable

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You need to implement a `Comparator`, for instance:

```
public class FishNameComparator implements Comparator<Fish>
{
    public int compare(Fish left, Fish right) {
        return left.name.compareTo(right.name);
    }
}
```

and then sort it like this:

```
Collections.sort(fishes, new FishNameComparator());
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still have one problem. I want to sort the arraylist in an activity. At the beginning stands:
    public class fishList extends ListActivity{
And when I write 
    public class FishNameComparator implements Comparator<String>{
It gives two errors saying: illegal modifier for the local class FishNameComparator; only abstract or final is permitted.
And: The type FishNameComparator must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator<String>.compare(String, String). I just did what stands in your answer.

Comment: @user1380611: If you are implementing this as a nested class, then it has to be a `static class`. And I messed up my example, it should be `implements Comparator<Fish>`.

Comment: Works perfectly for me.  Sorts in ascending order here.

Answer (score 89):

You can simply do it by this code:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Fish>() {
    public int compare(Fish o1, Fish o2) {
        return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: This one much better!

Answer (score 2):

*Kotlin code*

```
list.sortWith(Comparator { o1, o2 -> o1.name!!.compareTo(o2.name!!) })
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options how to achieve the same goal.
The easiest solutions would be utilizing Java 8 features:

```
Collections.sort(Fish, (t1, t2) -> t1.name().compareTo(t2.name()));
```