# Android ArrayList sort by a template

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

I have an arraylist of X elements. I want to end up in a situation where if a certain element exists then it will take up a certain precedence in the list .. for example, if element 1 occurs in the arraylist then it will be in position 0. However, if element 1 does NOT exist, then element 2 should be in position 0. Not all elements will occur in any single run of the application.

The elements are, of course, not called 1,2,3... but are complex string names - no ordinary sort is going to work. What is the best way of ordering the list? Is there a way of working with a template of an "ideal sort list"?

To make things clearer, lets assume that my "ideal" sort (if all possible precedent elements existed) was:

dog
cat 
rabbit

But the arraylist to be sorted was:

horse
rabbit 
cat
pig

Giving the order that I **want** to obtain from this particular app run:

cat
rabbit
horse
pig

Elements that have no precedence should simply occur in whatever order.

Comment: add an extra integer field priority to your list and sort according to that priority value. You can use hashMap for this.

Comment: Many thanks - my final solution was a combination of your answer and chiastic-security's. I added a hashmap containing a key/value pair where the key was the string and the value was the precedence. Then I added a precedence property to each object (cat, horse, dog, etc.) and passed the precedence map to each one. If the name of the object occurred within the hashmap then I copied the value of the key-pair to the precedence property of the object. Finally, I ordered the arraylist of objects by precedence using a comparater.

Comment: I am glad to know that you managed it. Could you post your answer for future visitors. That will help the community a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main class:

```
private final Map<String,Integer> precedenceMap= new HashMap<String,Integer>();

//CREATE A PRECEDENCE MAP SO WE CAN SET THE ORDER OF ICONS IN THE ACTIVITY
precedenceMap.put("Cat",0);
precedenceMap.put("Dog",1);
precedenceMap.put("Horse",2);
```

After we finish going through setting up all the animals (and they've all run themselves through the precedence map using the logic below), sort the list:

```
Collections.sort(AnimalList, new Comparator<Animal>() {
        public int compare(Animal result1, Animal result2) {
            return result1.getPrecedence()-result2.getPrecedence();
        }
    });
```

In the Animal object:

```
private int precedence=99;
private Map<String,Integer> precedenceMap= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

And pass in the precedence list we created earlier. If the label of the animal object maps something in the precedencemap then set the precedence of the object to the value in the map:

```
 if (precedenceMap.containsKey(label)) {
    precedence=precedenceMap.get(label);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.sort` to do custom sorting. You need to write a custom `Comparator` that compares two elements and decides which one is smaller (i.e., which one should come first). You then pass your list and your `Comparator` to `Collections.sort`, and it will do the sorting according to the ordering you've specified.

More detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853205/android-sort-arraylist-by-properties).